# How can I flip the layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to flip/mirror the tile-based layer in Openlayers and how? No mention in official documentation found.
I use **ol.source.Zoomify** as a source for **ol.layer.Tile** to draw high-resolution images.